# Site loading won't stop

Tags: php, wordpress

see https://jerryjazzmusician.com - the loading circle won't stop and I found that there is the following error:

PHP Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /home/jerryjazzmusicia/public_html/wp-content/themes/jerryjazzmusician/functions.php on line 2293 [02-Jan-2019 19:05:13 UTC] PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/jerryjazzmusicia/public_html/wp-content/themes/jerryjazzmusician/functions.php on line 2421

I am not sure how to fix this, I am not a coder and my developer is unavailable. What can I do?

Comment: Hi Clare! Can you please put the code of file `home/jerryjazzmusicia/public_html/wp-content/themes/jerryjazzmusician/functions.php` here or on pastebin? We need to see what is going there to help you :) cheers!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to autoplay a video from youtube. I don't think the error you noted is related to the persistent spinner.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately your developer will need to fix the issue but here is a temp solution.

The loader that is showing has a class on it which is "se-pre-con"

You can get that to disappear for now by logging in, going to editor under the appearance tab, selecting style.css, and adding the following css rule to that file:

```
.se-pre-con {
  display: none !important;
}
```

If this doesn't do the trick, we can look at a javascript solution.

Comment: JasonB, thank you, that did the trick, you saved the day! Thanks to all who responded. I don't know what I would have done.

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look at the source of the page. The spinning circle is an image (actually, a `<div>` with a background image), with a class of `.se-pre-con`. So I looked through the source to see what is supposed to make that div go away, and there was a **commented out** line that makes it disappear.

```
//Pre Loader
//(function(){
 //jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  // jQuery(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
  //});  
//}());
```

You'll just need to uncomment that, and that loading image will fade out once the document loads.